# Webservice Client - Unsupported Content-Type exception

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I'm calling a webservice through java-client. The message format is **SOAP**.  While calling the webservice i'm getting the following exception in Java

**com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html Supported ones are: [text/xml]**

Though I'm calling webservice with proper header and authentication credentials. I cant understood whether the problem is at webservice end or its in forming the message in Java code.

Comment: It seems to me that the web service produces xml output but you probably haven't set an accept header that accepts text/xml.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. Im creating SOAP message by creating SOAPEnvelope, SOAPHeader, SOAPBody etc object. Could you please tell me whether can I set accept header ? I would appreciate single line syntax.

Comment: We are having he same issue. the web service involved ignores the accept header returning application/xml. I would like to add an additional mime type to the allowed list.